# Page_Load is been fired when WebMethod is called through javascript PageMethods

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx page. I've added a ScriptManager to it, and set `EnablePageMethods=true`, and created a static method marked as [WebMethod] on the server-side.

I have always worked with WebMethods, and I've never seen this error before.
On javascript, PageMethods is accessible. But when I call my method, the `Page_Load` method is fired, instead of the WebMethod.

I've searched and found other people had this issue as well. But no answers.... Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

JS:

```
PageMethods.Test()
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Test()
{

}
```

Comment: What needs to happen for the JS call to `PageMethods.Test()` to be triggered? A button click?

Comment: Possibly.. or any other way. The `PageMethods.Test()` is been called correctly.

Comment: Right, but if it is through a button click and you aren't preventing that click to result in a call back to the server (via `event.preventDefault()`), that would trigger a page load.

Comment: That's true, but it's not the case. I tried calling it through different ways, and it is always the same. I've created another solution, and pasted the same code, and the WebMethod is called correctly. There must be something I'm missing out in the project I'm working with.... Perhaps something on the web.config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the problem on my case is that I'm using friendly URL's. Since `PageMethods` references the server-side page by its address, there you have the issue. It's been discussed here, on CodePlex: http://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com/workitem/3.

Apparently there are workarounds for this, but I ended up making a manual ajax call to a generic handler (.ashx).

Comment: Struggled an entire day slowly pin pointing the problem , eventually found a page method begin called. Googled the write issue and found your solution. Was the culprit

Answer (score 3):

So after founding the culprit of why controls in my update panel was calling post back twice I found it was because of a page method being called.

After finding LcSalazar solution I did disabled Friendly URLs and everything was working. But I find the Friendly URLs to be more clean so I found a solution .

On your master page add the following .

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            try {
                if (PageMethods.get_path().indexOf('.aspx') == -1)
                    PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
            } catch (e) {

            }
        })

    </script>
```

Once the page methods path includes the .aspx the page_load doesn't fire again.

Alternatively look into using ASP.Net Web Api . Better practice as well when it comes to reusable methods instead of declaring the methods in you Base Page or every page you are trying to use it .

Answer (score 0):

Disable friendly urls.  Comment this out in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

Answer (score -1):

When you submit a form that has runat server it processes the full .net lifecycle. Which fires the Page_Load of your .cs class. If you want to make it strictly want to fire the webmethod I suggest using an ajax call to your webmethod.

Comment: I am not submitting the form. I'm using PageMethods to call static server side methods. It relies on the ScriptManager, so it already uses ajax requests.